# Fitting the content to a single page in PDF

Tags: pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I am using xslt and fo to build a PDF. My requirement is to have the content of the PDF restricted to only one page.

Is some cases the PDF is coming in two pages. I have to avoid that. Below is the code for master set up.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="StandardPage" page-height="250mm" page-width="297mm">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom="20mm" margin-top="12mm" margin-left="14mm" margin-right="6mm"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="headerContent" extent="12mm"/>
                <fo:region-after region-name="footer" extent="20mm" precedence="true"/>
                <fo:region-start region-name="leftBorder" extent="14mm"/>
                <fo:region-end region-name="rightBorder" extent="6mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="StandardPage">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
```

Below is the content in the xsl. We have 18 options and the same is repeated 18 times.

```
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
    <fo:block font-size="18pt" font-family="ABC" font-weight="bold" text-align="left" line-height="14pt">
        <fo:list-block>
            <fo:list-item>
                <fo:list-item-label>
                    <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="4mm">
                    <fo:block>
                    <xsl:variable name="opt18" select="string(//void[@property='optionListEntryEighteen']/string/text())"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$opt18"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
        </fo:list-block>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Some times all the 18 options fit to a single page and some times 16 options fit to a single page and the next two options are being moved to the next page.

My requirement is to fit the options in a single page(If 10 options are being fit in a single page then show the 10 in that single page and don't show the other options.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not confident but how about using fo:single-page-master-reference & fo:block-container with @height and @overflow="hidden"? This is tested via FOP.

[Sample FO file]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
     <fo:layout-master-set>
         <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple-page-master" page-width="10.5in" page-height="5.5in">
             <fo:region-body margin-top="0.5in" margin-bottom="0.5in" margin-left="0.5in"
                margin-right="0.5in"/>
             <fo:region-before extent="1in" precedence="true" display-align="after"/>
             <fo:region-start extent="1in"/>
             <fo:region-end extent="1in"/>
         </fo:simple-page-master>
         <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="single-page-master">
             <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="simple-page-master"/>
         </fo:page-sequence-master>
     </fo:layout-master-set>
     <fo:page-sequence master-reference="single-page-master" reference-orientation="from-page-master-region()"
         writing-mode="from-page-master-region()" >
         <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="2em">
             <fo:block-container height="4in" overflow="hidden" border="thin solid black">
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (1)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (2)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (3)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (4)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (5)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (6)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (7)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (8)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (9)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (10)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (11)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (12)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (13)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (14)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (15)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (16)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (17)</fo:block>
                 <fo:block>optionListEntry (18)</fo:block>
             </fo:block-container>
         </fo:flow>
     </fo:page-sequence>
 </fo:root>
```

[The result]

[image: The result]

Comment: Thanks that really help:)